# selenium : how to click() elements inside div data-marker=""

Tags: selenium

I have this element where the code of the content is not inside normal html marks but inside a data-marker attribute of div :

```
<div class="profil-block d-flex firm" data-lat="45.812122" data-lon="3.112388" data-title="AGC CEGESMA" data-marker="<div class=&quot;profil-block firm w-auto m-0 p-0 no-box-shadow&quot;>
    <a href=&quot;/expert-comptable/5213-agc-cegesma-clermont-ferrand-63100&quot; class=&quot;d-block text-center&quot;>
        <img class=&quot;avatar&quot; src=&quot;/build/images/content/cabinet-anonyme.aa87fff0.svg&quot;/>
    </a>

    <div class=&quot;name w-auto mt-2&quot;>
        <a href=&quot;/expert-comptable/5213-agc-cegesma-clermont-ferrand-63100&quot; class=&quot;text-decoration-none&quot;>AGC CEGESMA</a>
    </div>

    <span class=&quot;address&quot;>
        <svg class=&quot;primary-red-icon mb-1&quot; width=&quot;18&quot; height=&quot;18&quot;>
            <use xlink:href=&quot;/build/images/design/icon-lieu-sprite.be93487d.svg#icon-lieu&quot;/>
        </svg>
        Clermont-Ferrand (63100)
    </span>

    <div class=&quot;info d-flex flex-row mt-2 justify-content-between align-items-center&quot;>
        <div class=&quot;d-flex&quot;>
                            <span role=&quot;button&quot; class=&quot;icon-block mr-2 firm-phone cursor-pointer&quot; data-id=&quot;260000451205&quot;>
                    <svg class=&quot;icon icon-tel&quot;><use xlink:href=&quot;/build/images/design/contact-icons-sprite.7e44022e.svg#icone-tel&quot;></use></svg>
                </span>
                                        <span role=&quot;button&quot; class=&quot;icon-block firm-contact cursor-pointer&quot; data-id=&quot;260000451205&quot;>
                    <svg class=&quot;icon icon-mail&quot;><use xlink:href=&quot;/build/images/design/contact-icons-sprite.7e44022e.svg#icone-mail&quot;></use></svg>
                </span>
                    </div>
        <a href=&quot;/expert-comptable/5213-agc-cegesma-clermont-ferrand-63100&quot; class=&quot;d-flex flex-column text-decoration-none&quot;>
            <span class=&quot;knowMore&quot;>En savoir</span>
            <img src=&quot;/build/images/design/plus.b2364558.svg&quot; class=&quot;icon-more&quot;>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                        <a href="/expert-comptable/5213-agc-cegesma-clermont-ferrand-63100" title="En savoir plus sur le cabinet AGC CEGESMA">
                            <img src="/build/images/content/cabinet-anonyme.aa87fff0.svg" class="avatar" alt="AGC CEGESMA – Expert-comptable logo">
                        </a>
                        <div class="d-desktop-none">
                            <h3 class="name">
                                <a href="/expert-comptable/5213-agc-cegesma-clermont-ferrand-63100" title="En savoir plus sur le cabinet AGC CEGESMA" class="text-decoration-none">AGC CEGESMA</a>
                            </h3>
                            <span class="address">
                                <svg class="primary-red-icon mb-1" width="18" height="18">
                                    <title>Adresse</title>
                                    <use xlink:title="" xlink:href="/build/images/design/icon-lieu-sprite.be93487d.svg#icon-lieu"></use>
                                </svg>
                                Clermont-Ferrand (63100)
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between -medium">
                        <div class="d-desktop-block">
                            <div class="name">
                                <a href="/expert-comptable/5213-agc-cegesma-clermont-ferrand-63100" title="En savoir plus sur le cabinet AGC CEGESMA" class="text-decoration-none">AGC CEGESMA</a>
                            </div>
                            <span class="address">
                                <svg class="primary-red-icon mb-1" width="18" height="18">
                                    <title>Adresse</title>
                                    <use xlink:href="/build/images/design/icon-lieu-sprite.be93487d.svg#icon-lieu"></use>
                                </svg>
                                Clermont-Ferrand (63100)
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="competence-list">
                                                            <div class="competence ">RAY François</div>
                                                                                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <div class="d-flex">
                                                            <div role="button" class="icon-block mr-2 firm-phone cursor-pointer" data-id="260000451205" title="Contacter le cabinet AGC CEGESMA par téléphone">
                                    <svg class="icon icon-tel"><use xlink:href="/build/images/design/contact-icons-sprite.7e44022e.svg#icone-tel"></use></svg>
                                </div>
                                                                                        <div role="button" class="icon-block firm-contact cursor-pointer" data-id="260000451205" title="Contacter le cabinet AGC CEGESMA par mail">
                                    <svg class="icon icon-mail"><use xlink:href="/build/images/design/contact-icons-sprite.7e44022e.svg#icone-mail"></use></svg>
                                </div>
                                                    </div>
                        <a href="/expert-comptable/5213-agc-cegesma-clermont-ferrand-63100" class="d-flex flex-column text-decoration-none" title="En savoir plus sur le cabinet AGC CEGESMA">
                            <span class="knowMore">En savoir</span>
                            <img src="/build/images/design/plus.b2364558.svg" class="icon-more">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I can retrieve the content with driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//div[@class="profil-block d-flex firm"]').get_attribute('data-marker'), but then how to i select some buttons for example inside this attribute?

I need selenium to click a link inside this data-marker code

Thank you

Comment: Which element are you trying to click within this data marker div? Can you share the url you're trying this on?

Comment: the url is https://annuaire.experts-comptables.org/recherche?localite=&lat=&lon=&type_localite=&comptable=&seed=8696. Im trying to click on the <div role="button" class="icon-block firm-contact cursor-pointer" data-id="260000451205" ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to click on an element thats only in the data-marker. In your situation though you can just locate this element:
[image]

This code should work for locating that element:

```
driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//div[@class="icon-block firm-contact cursor-pointer"]')
```